# How do I use a stored procedure from the client side (Silverlight Project) using Domain Services in a Business Application?

Tags: stored-procedures, mapping, ria, return-type, domainservices

I have a stored procedure that I defined in the database and I included it in my Domain Service and I also created the Function Import.

I have problems with mapping the return types.

Can someone guide me to some good resource? I googled and didn't really get any good help from it so far

Comment: You need to provide more information - **what** does your stored proc look like?? What does it return?? Why and how are you having problems mapping these return type(s) ??

Answer (score 0):

We have a good size silverlight application that uses many stored procedures. We use an RIA Service but Microsoft's auto code generator can have trouble with the return values depending on the complexity of the stored procedure. You might want to look at the auto generated code to see how it handles the return types. Just a thought.